# Multitouch desktop browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, multi-touch

I have made a multitouch surface ad it is pretty awesome. However, I am wondering if there is any desktop browser that supports multitouch as input and then exposes it either via an API or already smoothscrolls in a fashion similar to the iPhone.

Comment: Depends on your OS. The browser can't support multitouch unless the OS does as well. Browsers have no access to the hardware level input stream.

Comment: [Firefox 4 does multi-touch!](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/firefox4-beta3/)

Comment: Multi-touch support is probably independent of Mobile Safari-style scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 4/5 is the best option.

It also adds elastic scrolling to anything with a scrollbar as long as you use touch input.

Very cool!